# Uninitialized Value $` in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

This is my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    /(@.*)/;
    print $`;
}
```

It executes correct--printing everything before what's matched--but I get this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $` in print at FindAdd.pl line 6, <> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $` in print at FindAdd.pl line 6, <> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $` in print at FindAdd.pl line 6, <> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $` in print at FindAdd.pl line 6, <> line 4.
```

Of course, I can avoid this if I don't use warnings, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to avoid the warnings. Does $` have to be initialized?

Comment: Which version of Perl on which platform?  I used Perl 5.18.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks (compiled on 10.8 Mountain Lion) and don't get any warnings from the four lines: `aaaa@bbbb`, `@bbbb`, `xyz@`, `abcdef`.

Comment: I suspect the input doesn't match the regex, so $` was never set. This isn't the way you should be doing this anyway, though. :)

Comment: It matches for sure. To what are you referring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your test into a conditional.  if it doesn't match, then the $PREMATCH variable will be undefined.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    if (/(\@.*)/) {
        print $`;
    }
}
```

Also, to be clear of your intent, I would escape the @.  That way others will more quickly read it as a literal instead of wondering if that's an array.

Comment: Consider `/(\@.*)/p` ... `print ${^PREMATCH}` instead of using $`

Comment: or even: `print $\` if /(\@.*)/`

Answer (score 5):

The per-match variables are only set (and only cleared) by a successful regex match. Otherwise, their values are left over from the previous successful regex match.

It looks like you're trying to match the stuff before an `@` (an email address maybe?). So why not just do that?

```
if (/(.*?)@/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Stay out of the habit of using `` $` ``, `$&`, and `$'`, which have performance side effects. Alternatively, you can use the `/p` flag introduced in Perl v5.10, which has per-match versions of those as `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}`, and `${^POSTMATCH}`. These are documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

If I were doing this task, I'd reach for something like [Email::Address](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aAddress) which knows all about the special cases and formats.